# SSRS Report Viewer page hosted on HTTPS site, accessing SSRS Report server without SSL

Tags: ssl, reporting-services, https, reportviewer

I have a scenario where an asp.net page is using the `SSRS` reportviewer control to display a report. we recently updated the `IIS` server to use an `SSL certificate` and now the same application has a HTTPS URL.

Is it now, necessary to setup `SSL certificate` on the `SSRS` Report Server box as well?

Or, can the (HTTPS)web application continue to use the (HTTP) `SSRS` Report Server URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably far too late for this answer to help you, but yes, an SSL web app can communicate over standard HTTP to fetch reports. SSRS just uses a simple web service (an IIS site in SQL Server 2000 and a dedicated web server in 2008) so there aren't any real tricks involved.